# Still Need Internet Connection for Apple Music Offline?

Tags: apple-music

Do I still need data to play Apple Music "offline"?

Currently, Apple Music's downloaded music stops playing after 10 minutes of no data/no wifi.

Comment: What device and which OS version do you use? (e.g. MacBook 2016, macOS 10.13, iTunes 12.7)

Comment: I use the iPhone 7 with the default music app

Comment: The issue seems to have been fixed with the new iOS update.